# Automatic resizing when border content has changed

Tags: wpf

I have an application where I wrote my own Navigation Window (due to various reasons) and the Content is hosted inside a border. When I swap out the content I need a mechanism that notifies me as soon as the content has been rendered so I can automatically resize the whole window.

I need a behaviour that resizes the window to content or to a give maximum size. After the automatic resizing has taken place, the window should be resizable in any way by the user.

I am using:

```
this.MaxHeight = 700;
this.MaxWidth = 800;
this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Manual;
this.MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
this.MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
```

But since the rendering has not always finished, this does not work all the time.

edit: I wrote this sample to show that content rendered is only fired once:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border x:Name="border"
                Width="200"
                Height="200"
                BorderBrush="Cornsilk"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <Ellipse Width="40"
                     Height="20"
                     Fill="AliceBlue"
                     Stroke="Black" />
        </Border>
        <Button x:Name="btn"
                Click="btn_Click"
                Content="ClickMe" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtRender" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int rendercount = 0;
        Random rnd = new Random();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rendercount++;
            txtRender.Text = rendercount.ToString();
        }

        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Ellipse ell = new Ellipse();
            ell.Width = rnd.Next(50, 100);
            ell.Height = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            ell.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            ell.StrokeThickness = 2;
            border.Child = ell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.contentrendered.aspx?

Comment: Yes of course. But this event is only fired once when the window is shown for the first time and not when it's content is changed.

Comment: I just checked and it's working for me. The event is fired whenever i change the content of the window

Comment: That's strange. I will have to investigate this.

Comment: I added some code in my post, showing that it is not working.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this. In my case it is a window with custom chrome though and it leaves a huge ugly section on the right and bottom!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the size on the border, and only set `this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;` after `InitializeComponent();`

Working XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border x:Name="border"
                BorderBrush="Cornsilk"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <Ellipse Width="40"
                     Height="20"
                     Fill="AliceBlue"
                     Stroke="Black" />
        </Border>
        <Button x:Name="btn"
                Click="btn_Click"
                Content="ClickMe" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtRender" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int rendercount = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rendercount++;
        txtRender.Text = rendercount.ToString();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse ell = new Ellipse();
        ell.Width = rnd.Next(50, 100);
        ell.Height = rnd.Next(10, 100);
        ell.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        ell.StrokeThickness = 2;
        border.Child = ell;
    }
}
```

Comment: My main issue is that the content rendered event gets only fired once at the beginning and not when content changes (and thus has to be rendered).