# SizeToContent paints an unwanted border

Tags: c#, wpf, sizetocontent

Whenever I try to make a window and I set the `SizeToContent` to `WidthAndHeight`, on opening the window correctly sizes to it's contents, but it adds a small border to the right and the bottom. On resizing this disappears, and when using a set height and width this problem also doesn't occur.

This is a sample of what I mean:

[image]

You could say this is not a huge problem, though I find it makes my application look unprofessional, especially when I need to present this. Does anybody know why this is happening, or whether there is a workaround? I am coding this project in C#.

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="FPricing.InputDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="InputDialog" Width="400" Height="300" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="question">?</Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="response"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Values are passed on on creation of the class.

However I experience this problem on every window I have ever created, even without custom underlying code.

Comment: Show us the code you have for the open event, and it maybe a problem in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this tool](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com) (it's good, btw) I found that the `Border` control of the `Window`  (it's immediate child) doesn't fill the whole window, leaving that "border", which is actually the background of the `Window` control.

I've found a workaround. `Width` and `Height` of the `Border` are `NaN`. If you set those to an integer value, the "border" disappears.

Let's use the values of `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`, but rounded to an integer.

Define the converter:

C#

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class RoundConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return Math.Ceiling((double)value);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

XAML (remember to include your namespace, in this case "c")

```
<c:RoundConverter x:Key="RoundConverter"/>
```

Then create a style binding the size to the actual size using the converter. It's important to use a Key, so it won't apply to every `Border` (most controls use it):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="WindowBorder">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource RoundConverter}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource RoundConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

Finally, apply this style to the first child of the window (the `Border` control):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    GetVisualChild(0).SetValue(StyleProperty, Application.Current.Resources["WindowBorder"]);
}
```

If someone can do this in a simpler way, please share too.

Answer (score 13):

`<Window UseLayoutRounding="True" />` works for me.

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.

Comment: @Gabriel use rounding for only one Border, UseLayoutRounding will round whole Window.

Comment: For some reason, this lead to the problem that some labels got clipped (i.e. the bottom part of a g missing), so unfortunately it did not solve the problem (but BoJl4apa's answer works).

Answer (score 2):

managed to solve it, by **combining** Gabriel and smg answers.
Upon loading the window, get the border in question, and set its LayoutRounding to true.

```
this.Loaded += (sender, args) =>           
{
    var border = this.GetVisualChild(0) as Border;
    if (border != null)
        border.UseLayoutRounding = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, heres a related answer in which you can refer to a great answer.

[Automatic resizing when border content has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895814/automatic-resizing-when-border-content-has-changed)

So basically you want to add something like this, but put it to the values that you want:

```
<Border x:Name="border"
            BorderBrush="Cornsilk"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Ellipse Width="40"
                 Height="20"
                 Fill="AliceBlue"
                 Stroke="Black" />
    </Border>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, adding this removes the border on the right size, but not the one on the bottom. However this is not a big problem for me as this doesn't really look too bad. This quick response is very much appreciated!